# How to throw an exception using RxJava without OnNext

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I'm trying to force throw an error during the fake downloading using RxJava:

```
 disposable.add(fakeRepo.downloadSomething()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { a: String -> finished() },
                { b: Throwable? -> showError() }
            ))


fun downloadSomething(): Single<String> {
        return Single.just("")
    }
```

I found solutions only with onNext, but I don't want this in my code.

What I should do to invoke `showError()` ?
Currently I always get `finished()`

Comment: Throw an exception?

Comment: yes, throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Single.error`:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#error-java.lang.Throwable-

> public static  Single error(Throwable exception) 
>   Returns a Single that invokes a subscriber's onError method when the subscriber subscribes to it.